# Center align owl carousel items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

How can I align this owl items in the middle of the screen?

Tried: `center: true`

Please see in full page view:

```js
var owl = $('.video-thumb').owlCarousel({
  items: 7,
  autoplay: false,
  loop: false,
  nav: true,
  dots: false,
  margin: 30,
  center: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    640: {
      items: 2
    },
    768: {
      items: 3
    },
    992: {
      items: 4
    },
    1200: {
      items: 5
    },
    1600: {
      items: 7
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<div class="video-thumb owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="thumb-item">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="eMAM Cloud" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumb-item">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="eMAM Cloud" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

*It may contains any number of items.*

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vishnuprasadps/caLbn45t/)

Comment: changes loop `true`

Comment: @LaljiTadhani Sorry.. no need to loop items.

Comment: @LaljiTadhani You didn't need to edit the answer, just share link in the comments

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava check now

Comment: Check demo on https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/center.html

Comment: A more pressing question is why you are using owl carousel in the first place if you don't want any of its features?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava due to dynamic data.. sometimes its showing two items.

Comment: Then don't init carousel at all for lesser items. In any case using flexbox is not universal and once you have more items the carousel won't work

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava yes.. you are right..! but can you check this fiddle with more items [https://jsfiddle.net/vishnuprasadps/61eqwcb7/](https://jsfiddle.net/vishnuprasadps/61eqwcb7/)

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava why down voting? my question isn't have any unclear points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.owl-carousel {
    display: flex !important; /* To override display:block I added !important */
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center; /* To center the carousel */
}
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2z1qadv3/

Comment: Did you try this yourself?

Comment: i added jsfiddle

Comment: @vishnu You won't be able to get any carousel effect after using `flexbox` so why are you even using owlcarousel in the first place? Just make 2 simple divs

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava in this case effects visible only in small screen devices, if it having 7 or more items (dynamic control), should be able to scroll items with carousel effect.

Answer (score 1):

The carousel is the full width of the page, so it's already centered. If you want it less than full width you can add `width` style to the `.owl-carousel` and put the whole thing in a flexbox with `justify-content:center`.

https://jsfiddle.net/o0yk9rbh/6/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change owl-carousel to `display: flex` & `justify content: center`. Owl dots container is inside the owl-carousel. So set the width of the container to 100% & `justify-content: center`. This affects only to dots inside the container. Here is the hierarchy.

**owl-carousel 

|__owl-dots 

|___owl-dot**

Here is an example code to manually position dots in anywhere.

```
#my-carousel .owl-dots {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 12%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```